# On first successful connection, the prompt asks for password on Ubuntu Core

Tags: ssh, password, ubuntu-core

What password do I have to enter? I didn't setup any password.
I tried several different core versions and several core appliances such as https://ubuntu.com/appliance/adguardI have also tried and created a password to lock private key during the ssh-keygen process.
Nothing works.I can't login.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

These are my steps:
I'm following these instructions
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core

These are my screenshots of the process

Comment: The username and password will be the values you provided in Step 1, when you created an SSO account. Once you sign in, the key you uploaded will be downloaded and you will be able to SSH into the device normally 

Comment: This is confusing because you generally DON'T login to Ubuntu Core from a local terminal. In a properly installed Ubuntu Core, the console merely shows you the IP address so you can SSH into the Ubuntu Core system from a *different system on the same network*. Your first SSH connection requires the use of the public key you have on file at login.ubuntu.com (Ubuntu SSO). This suggests that perhaps you missed a step in the instructions, or perhaps you installed Ubuntu Server instead of Ubuntu Core.

Comment: Ubuntu [Core] *Appliances* generally don't have user access to the Core system at all. Any connection or configuration is done by the application, often using a web config page -- http instead of ssh.

Comment: Have the same problem, I can ping the tiny Pi but at ssh login, the firs one it ask for password. It doesn't wark at all, repeated all procedure, read multiple pages on the matter but could not get to a solution.